# How to remove the GUI wallet on Mac?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

How do I remove the wallet completely, also deleting the monero chain that I have downloaded?

I can't find the file path and I am a bit new on Mac. A short guide would be much appreciated.

I have secured my seed.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac, the chain and associated files are stored in this path `~/.bitmonero`.

The wallet files are wherever you placed them.

For the binary, just delete the application from your applications folder.

Comment: By convention, many Mac application config files get installed into **~/Library/Application\ Support/**.  Subdirectories will be named after their applications. Mac binary applications are installed into the **/Applications** directory.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner). It's free and works well. You don't have to worry about removing stuff on your own.